# Angular Tour of Heroes

Tags: angular, angular-tour-of-heroes

I am currently learning angular using the angular tour of heroes. I am slightly getting the concepts by following the examples. I am now in adding a new hero. For those who finished the tutorial, I just have question.

In the add hero, I can't get my head around it. Would you help me understand how the `addHero()` method added the new hero on the server? I am expecting a method that will do this. But I didn't see any add method.

I came from PHP/JS, jQuery background. So I was expecting something like this

1. `addHero()` method in hero.component.ts
2. `addHero()` method in hero.service.ts
3. Coming from PHP MVC, `addHero()` method in model that will update the data in the database.

Hope you bear with me, I want to understand how it works before proceeding to the next step.

Thank you everyone.

**src/app/heroes/heroes.component.ts (add)**

```js
add(name: string): void {
  name = name.trim();
  if (!name) { return; }
  this.heroService.addHero({ name } as Hero)
    .subscribe(hero => {
      this.heroes.push(hero);
    });
}
```

**src/app/hero.service.ts (addHero)**

```js
/** POST: add a new hero to the server */
addHero(hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
  return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, this.httpOptions).pipe(
    tap((newHero: Hero) => this.log(`added hero w/ id=${newHero.id}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<Hero>('addHero'))
  );
}
```

Comment: You might want to read a little bit more on observable (aka reactive programming). Easiest way to understand it is to read a bit on `rxjs`

Observable is like a `lazy` array with additional feature.  It will only runs when you subscribe to it.

Comment: https://rxviz.com/

Take a look at this, it might helps you to understand what is the `pipe` , `tap` and `subscribe`

Comment: Angular guide gives an introduction to observables: https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular - I don't think anybody on Stack Overflow will write a *different* tutorial. It's definitely very different from the way you described (although there is a whole book on reactive programming in PHP)

Comment: Thanks guys! So to understand it I need to understand Observables first. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

````
  name = name.trim();
  if (!name) { return; }
  this.heroService.addHero({ name } as Hero)
    .subscribe(hero => {
      this.heroes.push(hero);
    });
}```

Inside ts file, add function is called with name as param. The spaces on the sides are trimmed, again checked if there is a valid namestring. If not, it will not proceed. If there is one, a service will be called, with the name param passed and is subscribed. After subscription, if there is a response, the reponse will be pushed to this.heroes.

```addHero(hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
  return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, this.httpOptions).pipe(
    tap((newHero: Hero) => this.log(`added hero w/ id=${newHero.id}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<Hero>('addHero'))
  );
}```

addHero service calls the api and pass the name which was sent from ts to the api and if there is a correct response, this.log() is called. If there is an error, it is caught.

For more info about tap and pipe, go through rxjs docs.
````

Comment: Hi! Based on your explanation, can I say that the API(this.heroesUrl), has the add method/code inside it that adds the hero to a database/json object ?

Comment: this.heroesUrl is the url or the backend endpoint we are trying to connect to.
hero is the data we are sending.
this.httpOptions is the options/headers we are sending, if needed

Comment: Oh okay, I understand, yes. From what I understand, if this is used in a real life scenario, the url for example (/api/user/add), should contain the logic of adding the user  to a database, is that right? and then that api should return a response to addUser service.

Comment: Yeah, the controller behind that url in backend should contain the logic for DB connection and manipulation.